# Push a large file to 5k users via one drive

Tags: powershell, folder, onedrive-for-business, sync

I have a scenario where I want to copy a large file( say 5 GB )to around 5k users one drive.

The users have synced their ODB to their desktop.

Expectation is to place the file in ODB in such a way that it gets synced locally to these users system.

I know that using nGSC sync client we can sync the shared with me folder to desktop but for that to happen, end user would have to go to browser to start the sync by pressing the button on the ribbon.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just sharing read access to one single file rather than having to copy it 5k times?

Comment: The end goal is to push a iso file to these users system that can be executed after. SSCM isn't able to copy the files to users system for some reason, trying to find an alternative.

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off hosting it in one location and using domain policy to run a script that uses that location to download it to the machines, run it etc